# Apache Tika SourceCode Parser

Tags: parsing, apache-tika

I am trying to use the SourceCodeParser in Apache Tika to parse a c++ source file. However I am unable to retrieve the context. Has anyone worked with such a requirement before and could share their experience/knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: What isn't working? What do you mean by `unable to retrieve the context`?

Comment: `//parse method parameters
 SourceCodeParser parser = new SourceCodeParser();
 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(System.out);
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
 FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
 parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);`  

So, I am trying to print out the XHTML output but getting nothing. The file here is the path to a .cpp file.

Comment: When you say "parse a C++ file", just exactly what are you expecting to get?